# How to pass from server js and display JSON data on HTML view in tabular format

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, json

I want to display JSON data on HTML view. But sending stringified data won't allow JSON data manipulation in HTML view. I have converted the JSON object into the string using `JSON.stringify()`. But this restricts JSON data to be manipulate in HTML.

So I think the only way is to use JQuery in HTML. Could anyone please help me with this

**index.js**

```
/// connection made
app.post('/queryapp', (req, res) => {
  queryapp.execute()
            .then((json1) => {
                console.log('queryapp performed successfully!');
                json1=JSON.stringify(json1);
                const result = {
                    status: 'success',
                    message: 'queryapp performed successfully!',
                    json1: json1
                };
                console.log(json1);
                res.render( __dirname + "/template/demo/" + "home.html", {result:result});
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                const result = {
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'Queryapp failed: Check Certificate again!',
                    error: e
                };
                res.render( __dirname + "/template/demo/" + "grantform.html", {result:result}); 
            });
});
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell stretch-card mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-6 mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-12-tablet" align="center">
<div class="mdc-card">
<%= result.json1 %>   //this is displaying JSON string passage -- ERROR is here 
</div>
</div>
```

**JSON data**

```
{
  TxId: '642d747be002368dc4ebd74c0b1e1bb6eddb9c1d063a3b8dd0839cf2ea31ee13',
  Timestamp: '2021-05-20T08:10:52.336Z',
  Value: {
    class: 'org.papernet.commercialpaper',
    currentState: 'GRANTED',
    certNumber: '9010',
    collegename: 'scoe',
    examno: 40001,
    marks: '89',
    mspid: 'mhrdMSP',
    owner: '71000000H',
    registration_DateTime: '2020-05-31',
    student_id: '7171000000HH',
    grantDateTime: '2021-05-20'
  }
}
{
  TxId: '8b6494d42f6a4a89f6d781f409e28ead196a949199412188ccc53c262f557a15',
  Timestamp: '2021-05-20T05:19:28.175Z',
  Value: {
    class: 'org.papernet.commercialpaper',
    currentState: 'APPROVED',
    certNumber: '9010',
    collegename: 'scoe',
    examno: 40001,
    marks: '44',
    mspid: 'uniMSP',
    owner: 'sppu',
    registration_DateTime: '2020-05-31',
    student_id: '7171000000HH'
  }
}
```

I want this data to be displayed in Tabular format. Please let me how to address this.

Comment: what does happen if you change JSON.stringify to JSON.parse?

Comment: It shows - 'Queryapp failed: Check Certificate again!'
This this **index.js**

`catch((e) => {
const result = {
status: 'error',
message: 'Queryapp failed: Check Certificate again!',
error: e
};`

Comment: your console.log(json2) -> json2 is not defined. Maybe you should use json1=JSON.stringify(res); -> json1 is defined twice as parameter and variable

Comment: json1=JSON.stringify(res); will stringify all the {key:values} in JSON, thus it would be difficult to manipulate those key:values in HTML.